# Ajax form: Rebuild form and show popup

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

On my ajax submit form I would like to rebuild the form and show a dialog.
Here's the code I have used.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
if ($some_condition == false) {
    $form['play'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::play',
        'wrapper' => 'play',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ],
      '#value' => $this->t('Play'),
    ];
  }
  else {
    $form['unplay'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::unplay',
        'wrapper' => 'unplay',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ],
      '#value' => $this->t('Unplay'),
    ];
  }
}
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

return $form;
}

public function play(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();
  $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('test', 'asd', ['width' => '800']));

  return $ajaxResponse;
}
```

With the code above I am able to show the dialog but I am not able to rebuild the form.

So I have to use

```
public function play(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $form_state->setRebuild();
      return $form;
    }
```

But I will not be able to use AjaxResponse(); in this case.

How can I rebuild the form and show a dialog on submit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of returning the ajax wrapper you can add the ajax command `ReplaceCommand('#wrapper-id', $form)`. By the way you don't need to setRebuild() in an ajax callback because at this point this already has happened. This command should be in the normal submit handler as a fallback if js is not working.

Comment: It does not rebuild the form in the way I wanted it. I ended up creating something similar to Flags. I have an ajax link and the controller manages the requests sending back the replaced text I need.